# SQL MAX in two columns by statistic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
DECLARE @startTime DATETIME = DATEADD(MINUTE, -100, GETDATE()) --StartTime

SELECT   
    COUNT(*) Frecuency, mes.receivedqty AS Qty, ac.item AS Item 
FROM 
    mesReservationReceipts mes (nolock) 
INNER JOIN 
    ACCS_Reservation ac (nolock) ON ac.IDReservation = mes.idReservation 
WHERE
    ac.item IN (SELECT ac2.item 
                FROM mesReservationReceipts m2 
                INNER JOIN ACCS_Reservation ac2 ON ac2.IDReservation = m2.idReservation
                WHERE m2.receivedate > @startTime)
GROUP BY
    mes.receivedqty, ac.item
```

I get this result, but only I want the yellow highlighted rows - how can I get those? Please help!:

[image]

**Note**: I tried with `MAX(Frequency)` but that does not work because it should be grouped by the qty, and its the same case. I put a `MAX(Qty)`, but for example, if the `Qty` is more than `Statistic`, add in the table result (and I only want the real statistic qty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT Frequency,Receivedqty,Item,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by Item ORDER BY Quantity desc) as RowId
FROM (
  ----your query-----
  ))as q
Where q.RowId = 1
```

Comment: Thnks , i only have to change the partition

Comment: Yeah! Works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` to get the highest amount in each column.  Then filter:

```
select item, Frecuency, qty
from (select ac.item as Item, count(*) as Frecuency, mes.receivedqty as Qty,
             row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum_f,
             row_number() over (order by mes.receivedqty desc) as seqnum_r
      from mesReservationReceipts mes join
           ACCS_Reservation ac 
           on ac.IDReservation = mes.idReservation 
      where ac.item in (select ac2.item
                        from mesReservationReceipts m2 inner join
                             ACCS_Reservation ac2 
                             on ac2.IDReservation = m2.idReservation
                        where m2.receivedate > @startTime
                       )
      group by mes.receivedqty, ac.item
     ) ma
where 1 in (seqnum_f, seqnum_r);
```

Use `rank()` if you want duplicates, in the event that the highest values have duplicates.

Comment: OK, but in the last 100 minutes, was registered a new item, and in 'where 1 in (seqnum_f, seqnum_r)' only show me two items, how can i do to show more?

Comment: Wokrs too, only i had to play with partition and order by

Comment: @CarlosR93 . . . You can only accept one answer.  You can upvote as many answers as you like.